# Creating Plugin for CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, plugins, unity-game-engine, cllocationmanager

I am creating a iOS  plugin for unity3D. below is the code. How ever it is bombing out when [regionMonitor startMonitor] function is called with EXC_BAD_EXCESS. According to internet posts it seems like a memory management error. Can anyone see what is the issue here. thanks.

"RegionMonitoringPlugin.h"

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface RegionMonitoringPlugin : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager; 
}

-(void)leavingHomeNotify;
-(void)startMonitor:(float)latitude longitude:(float)longitude radius:(float)raduis;

@end
```

"RegionMonitoringPlugin.mm"

```
#import "RegionMonitoringPlugin.h"

@implementation RegionMonitoringPlugin

- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
   {
      locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
      locationManager.delegate = self;
      [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
      [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
   }
return self;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [self leavingHomeNotify];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [self leavingHomeNotify];
}

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)regionwithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Location error %@, %@", error, @"Fill in the reason here");
}

-(void)leavingHomeNotify
{
UILocalNotification *note = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
note.alertBody= @"Region Left";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:note];
[note release];
 }

 -(void)startMonitor:(float)latitude longitude:(float)longitude radius:(float)radius
 {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D home;
  home.latitude = latitude;
  home.longitude = longitude;
  CLRegion* region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:home radius:radius identifier:@"home"];
  [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
  [region release];    
 }

@end

extern "C" {

    static RegionMonitoringPlugin *regionMonitor;

    // Unity callable function to start region monitoring
    BOOL _startRegionMonitoring(float m_latitude,float m_longitude, float m_radius)
    {
        if (![CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable] || ![CLLocationManager regionMonitoringEnabled] )
            return NO;
        if (regionMonitor == nil){
            regionMonitor = [[[RegionMonitoringPlugin alloc]init ] autorelease];
        }
        [regionMonitor startMonitor:m_latitude longitude:m_longitude radius:m_radius];
        return YES;

    }
}
```

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I see it correctly, you should not `autorelease` `locationManager` and neither `regionMonitor`.

Add a `dealloc` method where you `release` `locationManager` instead. The `regionMonitor` should be released once you stop the location monitoring.

Comment: Thanks. That worked ! ... could you tell me why autorelease does not work ?

Comment: Because `autoreleasing` an object causes it to get released (and thereby destroyed in this case) once the methods return to their caller. So you are trying to access an object that doesn't exist anymore. If this is not clear to you, you should read up on memory management in iOS.